# cmake: install executables and create links to them

Tags: cross-platform, cmake

I'm using cmake and cpack to build my project and build packages. I'm creating a few executables in my project, let's call them `EXE1` and `EXE2`.

When creating different versions of these executables, I want to name to reflect the version of the executable (let's say `EXE1_1.0.0`). I can change the name of the output for a target by doing `set_target_properties`.

However, now when doing an `install`, I want to do create a symlink to this versioned name of the executable, i.e. I want to have

- the "versioned" executable installed in `bin` directory, i.e. `EXE1_1.0.0`
- create a symlink to the "versioned" executable, i.e. create symlink `EXE1`, which points to `EXE1_1.0.0`

Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Second question is:
How to install configuration files /etc/MYPROJECT/ directory? What DESTINATION I need to use for configuration files, like I use `bin` for executables and `lib` for libraries? Is using an absolute path like `/etc` an acceptable practice with cmake?

Comment: You should answer your own question here by posting the answer given to you on the CMake mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on cmake mailing list subsequently, and this is the response I received:

> The validity of the answer will depend on which CMake version you use
>   and which set of platform you want to support.
>
> Symlinks are not that portable
>
> a) Creation may not be [currently] done portably but if you are
>   targeting Unix    you can use cmake -E create_symlink to create one.
>
> b) Depending on the CPack generator you use and CMake/CPack version
>   symlinks may be embedded in the package or not.
>
> i.e. CPack pre 2.8.7 cannot create ZIP archive which contains
>   symlinks    CPack 2.8.8 can do that now.
>
> Then you can use an install(SCRIPT ... or install(CODE ...) to do that
>   at install time.
>
> Another option if you are using RPM is to use package specific post
>   install script. cpack --help-variable
>   CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE
>
> this last solution will off course only work for CPack RPM.

For second question

> You can use absolute destination path, they should be handled just
>   fine by CPack DEB and RPM, I don't know for other.
>
> If your software should be installed on Windows this is won't work
>   with archive generator (ZIP, TGZ, etc...) and/or NSIS.
>
> May be you can do something like:
>
> if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)  set(CONFDEST "/etc/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}")
>   else()  set(CONFDEST "etc") endif()
>
> install(FILES yourconffile DESTINATION ${CONFDEST})